# collection view has first cell always empty

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a custom Collection view in a Viewcontroller , whenever my Collection View is loaded always I get my first cell empty. How to remove this empty cell.

[image]

```
//CollectionView functions
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return collectionData.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! collectionCell

    let collectionData = self.collectionData[indexPath.row]


    cell.NameLbl.text       = collectionData["name"] as? String



    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let Info: NSDictionary = self.collectionData[indexPath.item] as! NSDictionary


    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "edit") as! editVC
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)



}
```

Comment: Show your tried code so far?

Comment: All data are dynamic? Show your collectionview data source Logic

Comment: Is that you checked your data source?

Comment: It may be your **collectionData** array's first index has an empty string. Check the values it contains.

Comment: @AhmadF how to remove that empty data?

Comment: @AhmadF Thank you :-) collectionData.remove(at: 0) worked !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on what is the case that you should handle hiding the first element, there are tow options that you might want to implement:

**1-** If it is okay to remove the first object from the data source (`collectionData` array), then you can simply remove the first element from it:

In your view controller (`viewDidLoad()`) you could implement:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    .
    .
    .

    collectionData.remove(at: 0)

    .
    .
    .
}
```

**2-** if you are required to keep the `collectionData` as is without removing the first element, but it should not be displayed in the UI, you will need to implement the `UICollectionViewDataSource` as follows:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // subtract 1
    return collectionData.count - 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! collectionCell

    // add 1 to indexPath.row
    let collectionData = self.collectionData[indexPath.row + 1]  

    cell.NameLbl.text = collectionData["name"] as? String

    return cell

}
```

That should lead to displaying the collection view as expected without editing the `collectionData` data source array.